# Windows Powershell error while registering the agent

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, group-policy, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to register an agent to Azure DevOps, but I get error like this program is blocked by group policy. Not sure how can I fix this.

Could someone help?[image]

Comment: this would maybe be more of a "hack" than a solution(which is why I comment) - maybe go to group policy and check if you can change it? or can you provide more context?

Comment: Did you examine the log for more details?

Comment: @WilliamMartens, I dont see any group policy specifically for this, there is turn on script execution,turn on logging etc for powershell..but I dont see anything relevant to this

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Yes even in log, the error is only this..I dont see any extra details

Comment: @priya Ah, I see. Okay, ill follow this to see if I can help further, but I advice to maybe check the log (Agent_20(...)0-utc.log)   `EDIT: Oh okay,`

Comment: You sure you dont need to enter some other text? or not leave the first field empty? (I don't think THIS is the case but, can it be the powershell version?) And also, can you try this? `Get-ExecutionPolicy -list`  (I think it was like that, I can be wrong)  it can* also be the "open with admin" perhaps? is it a windows client or server? (Im new to azure but not really to powershell, and since this is group policy I thought I could try to help)

Comment: @WilliamMartens which field you are talking about? powershell version seems to be the recent one and yeah I tried in administrator mode too :(

Comment: The default, (the blank one) `agent pool` and as it is a policy (this is "often" a problem with powershell) I think it is a execution policy(perhaps) even though it says group; so the `Get-ExecutionPolicy -list` maybe would reveal some details :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251080/discussion-between-william-martens-and-priya).

Answer (score -1):

According to the error message, it should be caused by the group policy.

Group policy is a nifty little Windows utility for network administrators that can be used to deploy user, security and networking policies to a whole network of computers on the individual machine level.

So, you'd better to contact your IT/System administrator to figure it out.

However, if you want to `hack` it, then please backup your registry, then try the following ways:

1.Disable the Software Restriction Policy using a `*.BAT` file:

Open a fresh new instance of Notepad. Copy and paste the following text into the blank instance of Notepad, then save it as a `*.bat` file (rename the file extension to `bat`), then double click on it to launch it.

Restart your computer after running the commands successfully and then try it again.

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Safer\CodeIdentifiers\ /v DefaultLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00040000 /f
```

2.Delete any and all configured group policies using the Registry Editor

Step 1: Hit `Windows + R` to open `Run` dialog and input `regedit`.

Step 2: Press Enter key, the Registry Editor will open. [Backup Registry](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-8/backup-registry-in-windows-8-8.1-computer.html) and expand the following keys and delete all items in the folders (`Microsoft,Policies,Group Policy`).

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
```

Reference [3 Ways to Fix This Program is Blocked by Group Policy Windows 10](https://www.isunshare.com/blog/this-program-is-blocked-by-group-policy-error-windows-10/).

Comment: Don't do this, this is dangerous. There has to be a normal way to do it, instead of removing vital registry keys (even if it's just to test) , it's dangerous.

Comment: also, wouldn't it be better to do this via the command prompt? so you see any errors, or log the full output to a file, **if you must use this method**.